# How do I find the underground corruption?

Tags: terraria

My large world went into hardmode, and the underground hallow appeared in a place that I've explored. Should the underground corruption do the same, or was that just coincidence? If not, how can I find it? Just keep digging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find the diagonal stripe of Corruption in your world is simply to walk along the surface, looking for an area of Corruption that you didn't notice before (this assuming that you've explored all of the surface from coast to coast). Quoting from the [Hardmode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode) wiki page:

> Immediately, two diagonal stripes of the new biomes, The Hallow/Underground Hallow and Corruption/Underground Corruption (or Crimson/Underground Crimson), are generated, replacing large sections of the World in a "V" or "X" pattern that extends from the center of The Underworld all the way to the surface.

So, these stretches are guaranteed to reach the surface level of the map. Finding this new area of corruption is made even easier if you took the time to corral the existing corrupted areas with a trench before entering hardmode (something I personally like to do to prevent the existing corrupted areas from spreading).

Comment: Virtually everything is covered in corruption in my world. Looking at a map, I probably could have found it by going to the lowest layer and looking upward for corruption. I was also looking near the hallow, since you mentioned they make an X or V, but while they're both diagonal stripes, they don't touch.

Comment: They occasionally will not touch, as you determined, especially if the world is very large. Note that corruption / crimson spreads much faster in hard mode, so it's advisable to contain what you can. The jungle biome can be swallowed if you're not careful.

Comment: I really don't know how. It's slowly eating my jungle top down, but it's just too large to seal off.

Comment: Find the edge of the corruption, go beyond it a few tiles (10 or so), and start digging a hellevator down all the way to Hell. Make sure the shaft is at least 3 tiles wide (corruption can't jump a gap that size). A good strategy for future worlds is to dig these kinds of shafts around the existing corruption areas before you enter hard mode.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to load it up in a map editor such as [TEdit](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Mod:TEdit) (which I sometimes use).

Outside of that, it's nothing more than just searching around manually. It should spawn as a slightly diagonal biome, and will spawn completely at random anywhere on the map. Digging down a ways and building a long horizontal pathway is probably the easiest way.

Just remember that it will now spread like the hallow, so eventually the area will be large enough to find its way to the surface.

Answer (score -2):

If you go to the underworld you can find the strip of corruption near the ceiling of the underworld, also if you find the hallow on the left go to the right to find the underground corruption (visa versa).